# Как после выполнения команды в терминале linux уведомить звуком?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, аудио, терминал, уведомления

Как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения длительной команды в терминале linux (ubuntu) выдавалось звуковое уведомление? (желательно вообще свой саунд)
Нарыл noti https://github.com/variadico/noti
удобно, но только выдает уведомление всплывающим окном. Опция `-s, -sound` есть, но работает только в OS X, а мне надо на linux. 
Впрочем, если повесить на всплывающее окно системный саунд, то тоже устроит. Как это сделать? Может просто включить тему звуковую и закинуть звуковой файл с определенным названием в папку /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/ ? или как?
Есть еще какие-то решения? Хочется чтоб один раз настроить и потом без танцев с бубном

Comment: Прописать запуск любого плеера после нужной команды через точку с запятой

Comment: Собственно, этот ваш noti и так прописывается через точку с запятой, просто вместо noti пропишите любой плеер :)

Comment: noti можно поставить и в самом начале команды без точки с запятой, то есть это 4 буквы, ну даже если после ; - это 5 символов. сколько символов минимально нужно прописать в случае плеера?  подскажите плиз конкретно самое короткое написание

Comment: Создаёте bash-скрипт с любыми необходимыми действиями (хоть плеером, хоть noti, что угодно), называете его к примеру `n`, помещаете в каталог `~/bin`, а сам этот каталог дописывате в переменную окружения `PATH`. Всё, становится достаточно дописать два символа `;n` :)

Comment: Если вы не знаете, как делать каждое из описанных действий отдельно, то, во-первых, это вроде как есть во всех вменяемых учебниках по линуксу (кстати, всё точно так же делается и в macOS тоже, а в windows не так же, но похоже), а во-вторых, про это возможно стоит задать отдельные вопросы на этом сайте (хотя высока вероятность, что вас отправят читать учебники)

Comment: ок, сенкс. Поставил пока beep. Примитивно, но работает. Нет ли кстати аналогов beep, столь же простого по юзанию, но издающего что-то более замысловатое?

Answer (score 0):

вот вам аналог noti на языке unix-совместимой оболочки:

```
#!/bin/sh

rc=${HOME}/.n.rc

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  eval "$@"
fi
if [ -f "${rc}" ]; then
  . "${rc}" >/dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

если сохраните его под именем `n` в какой-нибудь из каталогов, перечисленных в переменной окружения `$PATH`, то запуск:

```
$ n команда
```

или:

```
$ команда; n
```

после завершения указанной команды будет выполнено всё, что записано в файл `~/.n.rc`

в этот файл можете записать вызов какого-нибудь плеера, передав ему аргументом путь к файлу с понятным плееру содержимым. например, если у вас установлен `mplayer`:

```
mplayer /путь/к/файлу/со/звуком
```

Comment: большое спасибо